# Datediff with Blended Data Sources

Tags: tableau-api

I have two date fields that come from two different data sources.  One is from a CSV file of incident records, "Open Time", and one is from a SharePoint list "Go Live".  The two data sources are blended on a string value they have in common called "DB Name".

Also the SP list "DB Name" field has a 1 to many relationship with the incident records in the CSV.

I need to find the difference in days between "Open Time" and "Go Live" for calculated column I want to use as a filter.  Basically if the "Open Time" is 30 days or less after the "Go Live" date I want the incident record included.

I cannot figure out how to do that on a record by record basis with the aggregates Tableau seems to be forcing.  Anyone have a code example for this?

I have to do it in Tableau 8.2, I cannot alter the data in either data source.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Since SharePoint lists are not a supported Tableau data source, how are you connecting to a SP list? Are you using OData? Periodically pulling an Excel dump?  using MS Access as a middleman layer?

Comment: I am using an Odata connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to actually join those sources. But if that's not an option, there are some tricks with blending, but there are limitations

IF you have 1 to many relationship, you should use the "many" part as main datasource. This way, when you do

```
DATEDIFF('day',MAX([Open Time]),MAX([SharePoint].[Go Live]))
```

the relationship will be many to one, and not one to many, and the MAX() will do nothing.

The limitation is that this only works when you explicit the [Open time] on the worksheet, otherwise it will take only the MAX value.

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you explain the part about "explicit the Open Time" ?

Comment: You need to add [Open time] field on the worksheet. Tableau will always aggregate on the lowest level of detail that is available in the worksheet. If you don't explict [Open time] on the sheet, it will aggregate on whatever other field is there

Comment: To confirm, in this case [Go Live] is the one, and [Open Time] is the many.  Should it still be formatted as
`DATEDIFF('day',MAX([Open Time]),MAX([SharePoint].[Go Live]))`